# Is there a 3-dimensional airspace viewer?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, online-tracking, flight-tracking

I am using [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/) to have an idea of what the airspace looks like in terms of waypoints and airways.

I was wandering if anybody knows a website that displays such information but in 3D (or 3D + time) in order to navigate through the airways and check out some information as viable flight levels or altitude constraints.

I am imaging of a website/software that allows to navigate like on google earth or cesium and see what the airspace is like (qualitatively at least).

Comment: [These guys](https://glass.aero/) have some ambitious and very interesting plans. They're taking pre-orders for shipping in 2017Q3, but from what I've read they did that a year or more ago and then announced a big delay.

Comment: There are some usable Google Earth plugins, though they can be slow and imperfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download Google Earth airspace files for most countries, and move through them in 3D to explore what they would look like for various areas.  For example, you could see where you would be "under" a Class B shelf, or where you might navigate to avoid B/C/D airspace and "surface airport E airspace" (if you're flying an ultralight, for example).

These files can be downloaded from [3dairspace.org.uk](http://3dairspace.org.uk/airspace.html)

Here is a screenshot I just captured of the Seattle Class B, looking northwest from the southeast corner.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

#### NATS launches new flight tracking app

> National Air Traffic Services (NATS) has launched a new flight tracking app for iPads.
>
> The air navigation service provider said the Airspace Explorer app is the first of its kind to use “the same data that air traffic controllers use to safely guide the 6,500 aircraft that fly through the skies each day”, giving it the unique ability to track all aircraft in the UK, and to refresh “at a fast rate”.
>
> The app also provides a 3D view of the structure of UK airspace, giving users a sense of the altitude of aircraft, and of the shape and size of the areas of controlled airspace in the UK.
>
> — [businesstraveller.com](https://www.businesstraveller.com/business-travel/2017/04/10/nats-launches-new-flight-tracking-app/)

Above is a very recent app that does all the requested features including the shapes and sizes of the different control zones, but it only covers the UK.

---

- [iTunes link](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id1079364261) (free)